# Perform action when returning back to view controller via 'show' segue

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITableViewController that segues to a UITabBarController using a "show" segue. In the Tab Bar View, there is the navigation bar at the top with a left button to go back to the original Table View.

Is there a way to add actions to be performed when the user returns to the Table View?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` in your UTTableViewController. These are always called when the view is about to be or has been presented to the user.